Create index for id coluna In a Trino tablete
Is there a way to create an index or partition for an id column in parquet with an already existing patition for year, month and day?
My goal is to improve a Trino table performance when joining two huge tables by an id column.
We have two tables with more than 1 bilion lines, and when we need to join these tables, even when we filter the main table for one day (by partition year, month, day) the query returns an error “Query exceeded per-node memory limit of 64GB”.
